# How do i integrate django CMS to work with existing django project templates so i can manage my front end content easily?

Tags: django-cms

I have an existing django application that includes its own templates, now I want to use the capability of django CMS to enable the editing and updating of content in the front end easily. I have read the documentation and I understand that you use `{% placeholder "" %}` to include sections that you want to update, but I'm still not sure how or where to place the tags on my template or how to create them on the django CMS admin either.

Any explanation on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example base template I've got;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags cache i18n %}

{% load static from staticfiles %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    {% render_block "css" %}
    {% render_block "js" %}
</head>

<body class="body-page">
{% cms_toolbar %}

{% block header %}

{% block banner %}{% endblock banner %}

<header class="masterhead container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

    </div>

    {% show_menu 1 100 100 100 "partials/menu.html" %}

</header>

{% endblock header %}

<div class="container-fluid">
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}

    {% block highlights %}

    {% endblock highlights %}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The important part is to include `{% cms_toolbar %}` at the beginning of the `<body>` which gives you the CMS menu. If you then include `cms_tags` you can use the placeholders and if you include `menu_tags` you can generate menus from your page tree.

Comment: @gathagu well that's just an example of a template that in my case is my `base.html`, but the point is, if you want the CMS available, you need to have `{% cms_toolbar %}` included somewhere in the template.

Comment: It works, i seamed to have not added `{% show_menu 1 100 100 100 "partials/menu.html" %}`